# How to extract the value Num

Tags: php

Hellon

I need to extract the value but I am blocked after the loop ?

```
object(stdClass)#65 (1) { ["WSI2_RecherchePointRelaisResult"]=> object(stdClass)#64 (11) { ["STAT"]=> string(1) "0" ["PR01"]=> object(stdClass)#56 (8) { ["Num"]=> string(6) "098517" ["LgAdr1"]=> string(31) "LA DIFF " ["LgAdr2"]=> string(0) "" ["LgAdr3"]=> string(31) "RUE COURMONT 18 " ["LgAdr4"]=> string(0) "" ["CP"]=> string(5) "59000" ["Ville"]=> string(26) "LILLE " ["Pays"]=> string(2) "FR" } ["PR02"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (8) { ["Num"]=> string(6) "001424" ["LgAdr1"]=> string(31) "BOULANGERIE HUBINON LAMONT " ["LgAdr2"]=> string(0) "" ["LgAdr3"]=> string(31) "67 RUE D ISLY " ["LgAdr4"]=> string(0) "" ["CP"]=> string(5) "59000" ["Ville"]=> string(26) "LILLE " ["Pays"]=> string(2) "FR" } ["PR03"]=> object(stdClass)#67 (8) { ["Num"]=> string(6) "072109" ["LgAdr1"]=> string(31) "LES HALLES DE MOULINS " ["LgAdr2"]=> string(0) "" ["LgAdr3"]=> string(31) "40-42 RUE JEAN JAURES " ["LgAdr4"]=> string(0) "" ["CP"]=> string(5) "59000" ["Ville"]=> string(26) "LILLE " ["Pays"]=> string(2) "FR" } ["PR04"]=> object(stdClass)#68 (8) { ["Num"]=> string(6) "098428" ["LgAdr1"]=> string(31) "O MARCHE DES BISCOTTES " ["LgAdr2"]=> string(0) "" ["LgAdr3"]=> string(31) "RUE DE MARQUILLIES 33 " ["LgAdr4"]=> string(0) "" ["CP"]=> string(5) "59000" ["Ville"]=> string(26) "LILLE " ["Pays"]=> string(2) "FR" } ["PR05"]=> object(stdClass)#69 (8) { ["Num"]=> string(6) "002528" ["LgAdr1"]=> string(31) "MY AUCHAN WAZEMMES " ["LgAdr2"]=> string(0) "" ["LgAdr3"]=> string(31) "14 PLACE NOUVELLE AVENTURE " ["LgAdr4"]=> string(0) "" ["CP"]=> string(5) "59000" ["Ville"]=> string(26) "LILLE " ["Pays"]=> string(2) "FR" } ["PR06"]=> object(stdClass)#70 (8) { ["Num"]=> string(6) "005393" ["LgAdr1"]=> string(31) "CAR PRO SERVICES " ["LgAdr2"]=> string(0) "" ["LgAdr3"]=> string(31) "103 RUE BALZAC " ["LgAdr4"]=> string(0) "" ["CP"]=> string(5) "59000" ["Ville"]=> string(26) "LILLE " ["Pays"]=> string(2) "FR" } ["PR07"]=> object(stdClass)#71 (8) { ["Num"]=> string(6) "003124" ["LgAdr1"]=> string(31) "IMEDIAPHONE " ["LgAdr2"]=> string(0) "" ["LgAdr3"]=> string(31) "94 RUE RACINE " ["LgAdr4"]=> string(0) "" ["CP"]=> string(5) "59000" ["Ville"]=> string(26) "LILLE " ["Pays"]=> string(2) "FR" } ["PR08"]=> object(stdClass)#72 (8) { ["Num"]=> string(6) "002742" ["LgAdr1"]=> string(31) "EPICERIE SUPER 400 " ["LgAdr2"]=> string(0) "" ["LgAdr3"]=> string(31) "364 RUE DU FAUBOURG D ARRAS " ["LgAdr4"]=> string(0) "" ["CP"]=> string(5) "59000" ["Ville"]=> string(26) "LILLE " ["Pays"]=> string(2) "FR" } ["PR09"]=> object(stdClass)#73 (8) { ["Num"]=> string(6) "098425" ["LgAdr1"]=> string(31) "AUX DELICES " ["LgAdr2"]=> string(0) "" ["LgAdr3"]=> string(31) "RUE D INKERMANN 26. " ["LgAdr4"]=> string(0) "" ["CP"]=> string(5) "59000" ["Ville"]=> string(26) "LILLE " ["Pays"]=> string(2) "FR" } ["PR10"]=> object(stdClass)#74 (8) { ["Num"]=> string(6) "002898" ["LgAdr1"]=> string(31) "PHONECOM SERVICES " ["LgAdr2"]=> string(0) "" ["LgAdr3"]=> string(31) "273 RUE PIERRE LEGRAND " ["LgAdr4"]=> string(0) "" ["CP"]=> string(5) "59800" ["Ville"]=> string(26) "LILLE " ["Pays"]=> string(2) "FR" } } }
```

The loop

```
foreach($pointsRelais as $value) {
  if( is_object($value) && !empty(trim($value->Num)){
     var_dump($value->Num); // does'nt work
  }
}
```

Than you.

Comment: copy error code,change

Comment: Okay, now explain exactly what "does'nt work" means? That doesn't tell us what _is_ happening and doesn't help us help you.  What is the exact output from that line?